# Coup: Do you lose your coins when trying to assassinate a Contessa?

Tags: coup

In Coup if you claim to be an assassin and try to assassinate someone. If they claim to be a Contessa and you believe them you lose you three coins to the bank correct?

I had this argument with my friend, but to me it just makes sense it would be the same as if you try to take foreign aid and someone claims to be a Duke and blocks you. You can call them out and then if they were lying your action would go through. But if you don't the action is blocked so in this case the assassin would lose their coins and no one would be assassinated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you do lose the coins.  While the rules are not available online, this  [action flowchart](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/86105/action-resolution-order-flowchart) has been verified by the game's creator as being correct.  I'll go and try and find out what I've done with my copy and try and get a direct quote from the rules for you, but hopefully this should suffice.

Edit: Joe's comment is correct - although this is from the Coup: Reformation rulebook, it is under the basic rules, not the expansion rules.  On the fourth page, under the **Counteractions** heading, the last line reads *"If an action is successfully counteracted, the action fails but any coins paid as the cost of the action remain spent.*

Comment: As a rule if an action is blocked by another player using a action the costs of the action are still paid. The only time the costs are not paid if the action is challenged and the challenge wins.

Comment: And of course, thematically: you pay the assassin to do a job, and then in the course of the mission, she doesn't succeed, too bad for you. Assassins don't do refunds.

Comment: Reibello, the link you provided does not work for people without an account on the site. Could you possibly post a static link?